# Подключение голосового ввода в Android

Tags: android, google-api

Как подключить в разрабатываемое приложение голосовой ввод ? 
Подскажите какие-либо примеры или скажите в какую сторону копать?)
Заранее спасибо !

Comment: Как насчет погуглить? https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android+voice+input+use+in+my+app

Comment: Вообще-то голосовой ввод по дефолту доступен, при наличии интернета